# Write JVM heap dump to stdout

Tags: java, docker, heap-dump

We are using the following JVM flags to run a Spring Boot app inside Docker (managed by Kubernetes)

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp -XX:+ExitOnOutofMemoryError
```

As expected, the container gets restarted upon an OOM exception. However, the heap dump created on exit (in */tmp*) is no longer available as the container has been restarted. While we can map a persistent volume, is there a way in which we can have the heap dump written to STDOUT (as we already collect logs from STDOUT)? Using `-XX:HeapDumpPath=/dev/stdout` results in

*

```
Dumping heap to /dev/stdout ...
Unable to create /dev/stdout: File exists
```

*

Is there a simple work-around that I am missing here?

Comment: A HeapDump™ will mostly be huge (i.e., heap size, probably at least a couple hundred MB). Do you really want to dump it to std out?

Comment: I understand it can be huge. But, as I mentioned, we already route STDOUT content to our logging infrastructure which can handle the same.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use a [Docker Volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) to be mounted in the Docker image and store there the memory dumps that, as stated previously, can be GBs big.

Answer (score -1):

```
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/dev/stdout/`date`.hprof
```